# After a swipe left on a UITableViewCell in a UITableView, how do I programmatically close the swipe?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8

I enable swipe left on a row to show a action.  Upon tapping on the action, I want the swiped open table cell to close.  How do I go about doing that?

I've tried to `cell.setEditing(false, animated:true)` but setting editing doesn't close the swipe.

Comment: Try reloading the cell -- something like: tableViews's `reloadCellAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 6):

Note: I don't have enough reputation to comment on your question, therefore I would have to make some assumptions regarding your implementation.

If you are trying to close the cell in `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` you can try this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        // remove delete button only after short delay
        [self performSelector:@selector(hideDeleteButton:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
    }
}

- (void)hideDeleteButton:(id)obj
{
    [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
}
```

The reason for using `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` is the note in the [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW2)

> Note: The data source should not call setEditing:animated: from within its implementation of tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:. If for some reason it must, it should invoke it after a delay by using the performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: method.

All this was heavily inspired by the following answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22063692/2433921

Comment: After much fiddling, I found that the key is to call tableView.setEditing() and set editing to false on the table view.  I previously set editing to false on the cell that didn't work.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea behind the answer to use  `[self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];` in Objective C or `self.tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)` in Swift. Sorry, initially I didn't observe that you are using Swift